# Parse XML to get node value

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I want to parse XML string like this one:

`<Folk id="4630" country="US" name="Marry" />`

(which is placed in the rich textbox editor)

And fetch the `id`, `country`, `name` values.

**What have I tried:**

```
 Dim content As String = Me.RichTextBox1.Text
 Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument

 Try
      doc.LoadXml(content)
 Catch ex As Exception
      Label2.Text = "No XML Elements!!!!"
 End Try

 Dim items = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Folk")

 For Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In items
     Dim id As String = item.ChildNodes(0).InnerText()
     MsgBox(id) 'Try to prompt a message box containing the id=""
 Next
```

It does ends up with an error showing up: `NullReferenceException was unhandled.` - it doesnt found the `id` there, so I dont handle this error, first I would like to get the proper return, then I will handle if there is nothing found. So why it doesnt return the `Folk` `id=""` ? Is the access to the node called wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way that you are trying to reference the XML after it has been parsed.

Try changing this line:

```
Dim id As String = item.ChildNodes(0).InnerText()
```

To the following:

```
Dim id As String = item.Attributes(0)
```

`country` and `name` would be:

```
Dim country As String = item.Attributes(1)
Dim name As String = item.Attributes(2)
```

**edit:** sorry, I was speaking c# and vb.net at the same time. now fixed.

Comment: Yes. You're right, but when there is more than one `<Folk [..] />` it just does read the first one. `:-/` But at least its working...

Comment: I think if were many `<Folk [..] />` entries then they should be properly wrapped inside of `<Folks></Folks>` and then you would reference the individual `ChildNodes(x)` in the manner you originally tried.  Make sense?

Comment: The syntax would become: `Dim id As String = item.ChildNodes(0).Attributes(0)`